# Remove elements on list depending on previous element and preserving order

Tags: python, list

Let an object contain color and size, and a list like

`l = [<'GREEN', 1>, <'BLUE', 1>, <'BLUE', 2>, <'BLUE', 3>, <'RED', 4>, <'RED', 4>, <'GREEN', 5>]`

Each element is an instance of the object which contains color and size (not tuples). I've represented them in non-conventional way.

I want to eliminate elements from l only if the color of the previous element is the same. So l should be

`l = [<'GREEN', 1>, <'BLUE', 1>, <'RED', 4>, <'GREEN', 5>]`

List comprehensions or iterating directly on the list won't work, since I won't have access to previous element...

I know I can create a second list and only add to it if it's a "new" color, but I wanted to do it in-place if possible.

Comment: What are the list items? Did you mean tuples? Also, what have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I think a standard approach here would be to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> seq = [('GREEN', 1), ('BLUE', 1), ('BLUE', 2), ('BLUE', 3), ('RED', 4), ('RED', 4), ('GREEN', 5)]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [next(g) for k,g in groupby(seq, lambda x: x[0])]
[('GREEN', 1), ('BLUE', 1), ('RED', 4), ('GREEN', 5)]
```

where instead of `lambda x: x[0]` you could use `lambda x: x['colour']` or `lambda x: x.colour` or whatever the appropriate access is.  (See also `operator.itemgetter`.)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to iterate through sequence in a context of previous element is [with_prev](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/seqs.html#with_prev) function from [funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy) library:

```
from funcy import with_prev

[x for x, prev in with_prev(l) 
   if prev and x.color != prev.color]
```

(I assume here you have a `color` attribute on your objects).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, this should work:

```
def clean(L):
  x = 1
  color = L[0][0]
  while x < len(L):
    if L[x][0]==color: L.pop(x)
    else:
      color=L[x][0]
      x+=1
  return L
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `l` is a list of tuples, this would work:

```
In [7]: [(c1, n) for (c1, n), (c2, _) in zip(l, [(None, None)] +l) if c1 != c2]
Out[7]: [('GREEN', 1), ('BLUE', 1), ('RED', 4), ('GREEN', 5)]
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tested and confirmed that the following code will work. Partially inspired by the other posts here.

```
l = ["red","red","green","blue","green","green"]

k = 1
while k < len(l):
  if l[k-1]==l[k]:
    del l[k]
    k = k + 1
  else:
    k = k + 1
for x in range(len(l)):
    print l[x]
```

Output:

```
red
green
blue
green
```

Comment: I didn't want to use an extra array. But looks like it's the simplest way :(

Comment: I think so as replacing a nullifying elements in the array you are already searching, while possible, would get really messy really quick.

Comment: @Kyle: :) for the back-inspiration. Well, the increment after the delete is wrong. when I test it, the Blue,3 is not deleted. What development environment do you use? Mine is python 2.7.5 and python 3.3.5 on a Mac and python 2.7.3 on Raspian. There should be no difference, but it is confusing me, that you are stuck in the loop with my code.

Comment: I've used 3.4 and an online compiler for 2.7, both responded with the correct output.

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by Kyle, this code:

```
l = [['GREEN', 1], ['BLUE', 1], ['BLUE', 2], ['BLUE', 3], ['RED', 4], ['RED', 4], ['GREEN', 5]]

k = 1
while k < len(l):
    if l[k-1][0] == l[k][0]:
        del l[k]
    else:
        k += 1
    print(k,'  ',l)
print('---')
print(l)
```

gives (2.7 & 3.3):

```
2    [['GREEN', 1], ['BLUE', 1], ['BLUE', 2], ['BLUE', 3], ['RED', 4], ['RED', 4], ['GREEN', 5]]
2    [['GREEN', 1], ['BLUE', 1], ['BLUE', 3], ['RED', 4], ['RED', 4], ['GREEN', 5]]
2    [['GREEN', 1], ['BLUE', 1], ['RED', 4], ['RED', 4], ['GREEN', 5]]
3    [['GREEN', 1], ['BLUE', 1], ['RED', 4], ['RED', 4], ['GREEN', 5]]
3    [['GREEN', 1], ['BLUE', 1], ['RED', 4], ['GREEN', 5]]
4    [['GREEN', 1], ['BLUE', 1], ['RED', 4], ['GREEN', 5]]
---
[['GREEN', 1], ['BLUE', 1], ['RED', 4], ['GREEN', 5]]
```

Comment: while this could work, wouldn't you also end up with errors dealing with list size because you would be deleting elements that were once the size. Wouldn't you get index out of range?

Comment: Try it, I do not get one. The counter does not count until 5 (insert some print(k,'  ',l)). I am not sure, but I think Python is referencing l in len(l), so it should be good.

Comment: Ah hold on. I see whenever I try to run it it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop.